# 0MQ .NET support for UDP

Tags: .net, udp, zeromq

I need to move away from TCP to UDP transport in my .net application. Using udp transport with ZeroMQ (.net binding) complains that the transport is not supported. I understand that the Native "NetMQ" implementation clearly does not support UDP but what about clrzmq4, which I understand is a wrapper over libzmq, not support UDP either? Do I need to use raw UDP sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the [documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-bind) for the `zmq-bind` call.

The supported transports are:

```
tcp
ipc
inproc
pgm, epgm
vmci
```

[epgm](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-pgm) is pgm over udp

> "Encapsulated PGM" or EPGM where PGM datagrams are encapsulated inside UDP datagrams (the epgm transport).

So if all you're doing is PUB/SUB and you can multicast over epgm, that is an option, otherwise, it seems like doing away with ZeroMQ is your only option.  But, you would also be doing away with a lot of its functionality at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can also do pure UDP with new socket types DISH and RADIO, which similar to PUB-SUB.

Take a look at the test for a usage example:

https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/tests/test_udp.cpp